# How to concat multiple array into single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to concat all this array into a single array:

```
[Array(10), Array(10), Array(10), Array(10), Array(10), Array(10), Array(10), Array(2)]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Use `reduce` and `concat`

```
var output = arr.reduce( (a, c) => a.concat(c), []); //assuming arr is the input array
```

**Edit**

As @TJ mentioned in his comment, that above solution will create some intermediate arrays along the way, you can try (`concat` without *spread*)

```
var output = [].concat.apply([], arr);
```

or

```
var output = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr); //avoiding usage of another unnecessary array `[]`
```

Comment: Producing unnecessary intermediate arrays along the way... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder *unnecessary intermediate arrays* True, Or `[].concat.apply([], arr)` would suffice

Comment: Or you could avoid that last unnecessary array [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49066319/how-to-concat-multiple-array-into-single-array/49066344?noredirect=1#comment85137775_49066381).

Answer (score 4):

You can use ES6's `spread`:

```js
var arrays = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];
var res = [].concat(...arrays);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Good thought making use of `concat`'s handling of multiple arguments.

Comment: @Bikshu s (and lurkers): If you can't use spread, the above is effectively: `var res = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arrays);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];

console.log(array1.concat(array2));
// expected output: Array ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

If you have an array of array you can do like so :

```
let bigArray = new Array();

arrayOfArray.forEach((arr) => {
    bigArray.concat(arr);
});
```